# C++ WinAPI - cleanup before windows shutdown terminates the process?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Typically, you can capture the `WM_CLOSE` event to do cleanup tasks before the application terminates, when working with GUI windows.

However, if my application just runs in the background and the process is terminated only when windows is shut down - is there any way to capture this event and perform some cleanup before the process is terminated?

I know that it's not possible to intervene with the task managers process closing. But with the shutdown I just noticed there is a `shutdown` and a `shutdown /F` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a [message-only window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only), and handle the [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890.aspx) and/or [WM_ENDSESSION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889.aspx) messages.